# Netlogo: identifying expanding neighbors

Tags: netlogo

I am struggling with coding identifying an expanding neighborhood based on an attribute of a patch. I need to be able to first identify a patch with a turtle present, then identify if that patches 4 neighbors have turtles, then if the neighbors of the neighbors have turtles, etc... until a threshold of patches is reached. I would really appreciate any guidance/help.

This is the code I have now:

'Clusters' is an agentset representing patches with turtles
'Cluster-ring' represents the distance from the original patch (in terms of rings of neighboring patches)
Cluster-ID is the id number of the clusters center patch.

```
ask clusters [if any? turtles-here
[ask neighbors4
[set pcolor orange - 3
 set cluster? TRUE
 set cluster-ID [cluster-ID] of myself
 set cluster-ring 2
 ]]]



ask clusters with [cluster-ring = 2][if any? turtles-here
[ask neighbors4
[set pcolor orange - 5
set cluster? TRUE
set cluster-ID [cluster-ID] of myself
set cluster-ring [cluster-ring] of myself + 1
]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your setup is like, but here's one approach that I think does what you need. It works as follows (once the world has been scattered with turtles):

- Randomly select a number of patches with turtles present that also have `neighbors4` that also have turtles present (procedure name here `cluster-node-find`). In this example I've called them nodes, and I've randomly chosen to start with 5. Next, ask these nodes to:

  - Set `cluster?` to `true`
  - Randomly choose a `cluster-ID`
  - Set their `cluster-ring` value to 0 (since they are the "center" of a ring)
- Once nodes have been chosen, grow the cluster with a procedure that will grow the outer ring by one each time it is called (I've called it `build-cluster` here). So, ask any patches with `cluster?` set to `true` that doesn't have any `neighbors4` without a turtle to:

  - Ask any `neighbors4` that are not already part of a cluster to:
  - Set `cluster?` to `true`
  - Take on the `cluster-ID` of the asking patch
  - Set their `cluster-ring` value to the `cluster-ID` of the asking patch + 1
- Repeatedly run that `build-cluster` procedure to watch your clusters grow outward, stopping where there are gaps in turtle presence.

Obviously, you may need to modify this based on how you setup your clusters initially, but it may get you pointed in the right track as to how to build outward. See below for a full program that shows how this works- use a `setup` button to call this chunk:

```
patches-own [ cluster? cluster-ID cluster-ring ]

to setup
  ca
  ask patches [
    set pcolor 103
    set cluster? false
    set cluster-ID -999
    set cluster-ring -999
  ]

  ask n-of ( round count patches * 0.75) patches [
    sprout 1 [
      set shape "circle"
      set size 0.5
      set color white
    ]
  ]
  cluster-node-find
  reset-ticks  
end

to cluster-node-find 
  let potential-clusters n-of 5 patches with [ 
    cluster? = false and 
    any? turtles-here and
    not any? neighbors4 with [ not any? turtles-here ]
  ]

  ask potential-clusters [
    set pcolor red + 4
    set cluster? true
    set cluster-ID random 10000   
    set cluster-ring 0
    ask turtles-here [
      set color black
    ]
  ]  
end
```

Then, make a forever button for this `build-cluster` if you want to see them grow out to the end:

```
to build-cluster
  let cluster-members patches with [ 
    cluster? and
    not any? neighbors4 with [ not any? turtles-here ]
  ]
  ask cluster-members [
    ask neighbors4 with [ cluster? = false and any? turtles-here ] [
      set pcolor [pcolor] of myself - 0.25 
      set cluster? true
      set cluster-ID [cluster-ID] of myself 
      set cluster-ring ( [cluster-ring] of myself + 1 )
    ]
  ]
  tick
end
```

**EDIT:**

As per the question in the comment below:

Here is the output using:

```
let cluster-members patches with [ 
    cluster? and
    not any? neighbors4 with [ not any? turtles-here ]
  ]
```

in the `build-cluster` procedure.

[image]

If you instead use:

```
let cluster-members patches with [ 
    cluster? and
    any? neighbors4 with [ any? turtles-here ]
  ]
```

There is no restriction where the clusters need to have their leading edge expand through patches that have turtles present on their `neighbors4`. So, the cluster expands much further and the only gaps will be where turtles are not present (assuming high enough turtle density):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Luke! That's amazing and I really appreciate it. I have one question regarding in the build clusters procedure: Why do you use the 'not any neighbors4 with [not any? turtles-here]' syntax instead of 'any? neighbors4 with any? turtles-here]? I understand the code, but am curious about the logic.

Comment: @Switters- Good question- if you do `any? neighbors4 with [ any? turtles-here]` you will not have it expand by rings- any patch with a turtle would qualify as a new node on the expanding edge of the cluster. If you modify the code to try it you'll see that the clusters expand even through patches that do *not* have four neighbors that all have turtles. If you just want it to expand outward without that check, definitely modify the code as you describe- I was basing this on your " identify if that patches 4 neighbors have turtles" line. I'll throw some images at the end of my answer to clarify!

Comment: --That makes perfect sense. Again, I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @Switters - No worries, I'm happy to help!